# Uploading a file via paperclip through an external script

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I'm trying to create a rails app that is a CMS for a client. The app currently has a documents class that uploads the document with paperclip.

Separate to this, we're running a python script that accesses the database and gets a bunch of information for a given event, creates a proposal word document, and uploads it to the database under the correct event.

This all works, but the app does not recognize the document. How do I make a python script that will correctly upload the document such that paperclip knows what's going on?

Here is my paperclip controller:

```
def new
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @document = Document.new
end

def create
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @document = @event.documents.new(document_params)
    if @document.save 
        redirect_to event_path(@event) 
    end
end

private

def document_params
    params.require(:document).permit(:event_id, :data, :title)
end
```

Model

```
validates :title, presence: true
    has_attached_file :data
    validates_attachment_content_type :data, :content_type => ["application/pdf", "application/msword"]
```

Here is the python code.

```
f = open(propStr, 'r')

binary = psycopg2.Binary(f.read())

self.cur.execute("INSERT INTO documents (event_id, title, data_file_name, data_content_type) VALUES (%d,'Proposal.doc',%s,'application/msword');" % (self.eventData[0], binary))

self.con.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use Ruby to script this since it can load in any model information or other classes you need.

But assuming your requirements dictate the use of python, be aware that Paperclip does not store the documents in your database tables, only the files' metadata. The actual file is stored in your file system in the /public dir by default (could also be s3, etc depending on your configuration). I would make sure you were actually saving the file to the correct anticipated directory. The default path according to the [docs](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#file) is:

```
:rails_root/public/system/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename
```

so you will have to make another sql query to retrieve the id of your new record. I don't believe pdfs have a :style attribute since you don't use imagicmagick to resize them, so build a path that looks something like this:

```
/public/system/documents/data/000/000/123/my_file.pdf
```

and save it from your python script.